# Paypal express checkout recurring payment with credit/debit card next steps

Tags: express, paypal, payment-gateway, express-checkout, recurring-billing

I have integrated paypal express checkout on my website. Currently with paypal account Pay as go and recurring/subscription payment both works as expected.

Now I am trying to integrate credit/debit card purchases for my website. 
At first , in order to do that I have enabled "PayPal Account Optional" is "ON" in my PayPal account and set following on express checkout parameters SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole and LANDINGPAGE=Billing. After doing these steps
for only pay as go payment on paypal site "Check out as a guest" option showing but for recurring/subscription payment "Check out as a guest" is not showing.

Please kindly guide me on following:

What I have to do in express checkout functionality in order to enable paying through credit/debit card directly  ?

Why paying through credit/debit is not showing for recurring/subscription payment ?

Whether it's possible or not to integrate credit/debit card functionality with express checkout?

Thank you in advance for your guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with Express Checkout and Recurring Payments the user has to create an account or sign in.  Guest checkout is not available with recurring payments.

To setup profiles with credit cards you'll need to sign up for PayPal Payments Pro.  Pro itself costs $30/mo, and then you'll have to add Recurring Billing on top of that, which is another $30/mo.

Sometimes they'll negotiate with you on those monthly fees depending on the volume you'll be doing.  You may want to give PayPal a call.

Once that's all activated on your account you'll just use CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile on its own, and you'll pass the CC details directly into that.  So you'll be building the CC form on your site, which means you'll need an SSL to protect it, and you'll need to make sure you don't save any credit card details on your own server in the database, in log files, or anywhere.